# Why is www.rabbitmq.com unreachable?

Tags: rabbitmq

Does anyone know if the project is no more or if they just have problems with their server?

http://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: http://www.rabbitmq.com/  works correctly

Comment: It's back up. Phew. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [their twitter](https://twitter.com/RabbitMQ/status/573051967846678528), the site went down at ~9:20UTC:

> Our hosting provider seems to have dropped off the internet, so
>   http://www.rabbitmq.com/  is down. We apologise profusely.

And [back up](https://twitter.com/RabbitMQ/status/573064133270220800) around ~10:15UTC

> .@RabbitMQ ...and it's back. Thanks for your patience.

In the future it's best to check their twitter and http://isup.me/rabbitmq.com.